# How to free resources and dispose injected service in ASP.NET 5/Core by the end of request?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I have a service which is injected into a controller using the ASP.NET Core's default Dependency Injection Container:

```
public class FooBarService : IDisposable {
    public void Dispose() { ... }
}

services.AddScoped<FooBarService>();
```

This creates one instance per request. How to ensure that the framework would dispose the FooBarService instance by the end of each request, without relying on destructors and garbage collection?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Like the all other DI containers, it will dispose IDisposable instances for you with respecting life time of instance.

In your stuation, if instance is registered as `Scoped` (Instance Per Request). It will dispose this instance after request is completed.

**Edit**:
In official documents they don't mention this.
So Let's check source code to be sure:

When a scope is created, [ServiceScopeFactory](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/blob/4f2e6f035662b73936a2ed4fc249c163c9978c91/src/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/ServiceLookup/ServiceScopeFactory.cs) returns a new [ServiceScope](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/blob/4f2e6f035662b73936a2ed4fc249c163c9978c91/src/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/ServiceLookup/ServiceScope.cs) which is depended with [ServiceProvider](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/blob/4f2e6f035662b73936a2ed4fc249c163c9978c91/src/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/ServiceProvider.cs) and disposable.

`ServiceProvider` has  `private List<IDisposable> _transientDisposables;` which keeps disposable services when `TransientCallSite` is `invoke`d  in `CaptureDisposable` method. Also `ServiceProvider` has `private readonly Dictionary<IService, object> _resolvedServices = new Dictionary<IService, object>();` which keeps all services for `Scoped`.

When liftime/scope finishes, the `ServiceScope` is disposed. Then it disposes `ServiceProvider` which disposes all `_transientDisposables` and then it checks `_resolvedServices` and disposes disposable services in the dictionary in `ServiceProvider`.

**Edit**(13.06.2017): They mention in official documents now. [Service Lifetimes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-8.0#service-lifetimes)

Comment: I can't find a place in the documentation, where it says about disposing directly. Could you probably point me to the right piece of text?

Comment: [It handles the lifetime (when to create an object and when to dispose it) of the injected object.](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/7751fa4c-5638-4090-bb4a-4c5f0a2513da.aspx)

Comment: I have the problem with it. I have added a data store context as AddScoped. Now it seems that it is resused. The constructor is hit only one for multiple request and Dispose is never requested. PLus my limit on Document DB seems that lode is constant. Any way I can check what is not correct?

I also have created the Id prperty as:
this.id = Guid.Newuid();
and it is the same for all requests.

Comment: @SzymonSasin Can you be sure parent classes of Data StoreContext are not Singleton ?. If one of them singleton all child objects will be singleton also.

Comment: @ErkanDemirel If only the container had [diagnostic services that could detect these lifestyle mismatches](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/LifestyleMismatches.html)

Comment: @ErkanDemirel the docs now do explicitly mention this (see [Disposing of services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection#designing-your-services-for-dependency-injection)), so you may want to update your answer to point there.

Answer (score 8):

When using AddScoped, it's [by design](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/dependency-injection.html#service-lifetimes-and-registration-options) that the object will have its lifetime associated with the Request.

Answer (score 5):

I see no one mentioned this yet, but besides implementing `IDisposable` in your type, you can also use `{HttpContext}.Response.RegisterForDispose(objectToDispose)`. Typically this is used to register an object at the start of a request (such as a controller action) to be disposed when the request ends.