# Do I need to dispose objects in my controller mvc6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, idisposable

I'm building a small app that using ASP.Net Core MVC6.

In `ConfigureServices`, I inject my repositories like this:

```
...
services.AddScoped<IRepository<User>, AccountRepository>();
...
```

I implemented the dispose pattern by cleaning the db context.

Here's the code:

```
public class AccountRepository : IRepository<User>
{
    private readonly Db _context;
    public AccountRepository(Db context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void Add(User obj)
    {
        _context.Users.Add(obj);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
    public void Update(User obj)
    {
        _context.Users.Update(obj);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    #region Get
    public User Get(string id)
    {
        return _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name == id);
    }
    #endregion Get

    #region Destroy
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _context.Dispose();
            }
        }
        this.disposed = true;
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    #endregion Destroy
}
```

I want to know if I need to also dispose the repository in my controller.

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly IRepository<User> _accountRepository;
    // Do I need a dispose in here??
    public AccountController(IRepository<User> repository)
    {
        _accountRepository = repository;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

In the [doc](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/dependency-injection.html#service-lifetimes-and-registration-options), it's says:

> Scoped objects are the same within a request, but different across different requests

Does it means that the object is destroyed once the request is completed? Or do I need to dispose it in the controller?

Comment: As a matter of practice, I do it.  Place a breakpoint on your repository dispose call and you'll see it gets called eventually, but I like explicitly calling dispose to ensure the connection is closed and disposed of when the request is complete.

Comment: You are right, I could have put a break point to check that!

Comment: I was just thinking about the dependency injection.  If I recall MVC6 has its own.  I would look into how the instance lifetimes are scoped (i.e. is a new instance of the repository created for each request?).  Just a thought... but I doubt it'll cause any issues.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using the one given by default.

Comment: The only thought that crossed my mind would be - if you were to somehow make a call across multiple controllers in a single request, but I can't think of how that would be feasible (or possible).

Comment: You have implemented Dispose(), now declare you are using the `IDisposable` interface then wrap your usage in `using` and let it take care of itself.

Comment: @Jasen: It useless to use `using` in each action, since the object is already created by the default Ioc.

Comment: The DI container should take care of object lifetime. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35872163/how-to-free-resources-and-dispose-injected-service-in-asp-net-5-core-by-the-end).

Comment: They should put that in the doc.