# Microsoft.Extension.Dependencyinjection problems

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am making a RESTfull API with asp net core 1.1, this is my first time using net core and I am getting fairly confused.

I need to access a neo4j database from within my application, but I want to only have to setup a connection to the database once so that for every request I don't have to re connect to the database. So I have created a class that will deal with making the connection and then there is a newSession() method that will fairly obviously return a new ISession instance that I can query the database with.

This is the code that I currently have:

```
namespace DependencyInjection.Interfaces
{
    public interface IDatabaseSessionRepository
    {
        IDriver Driver { get; set; }

        void IDatabaseSessionRepository();

        ISession newSession();
    }

    public interface IDatabaseRepository
    {
        ISession Session { get; set; }

        void IDatabaseRepository();
    }
}
```

and

```
namespace DependencyInjection.Methods
{ 
    public class DatabaseSessionRepository : IDatabaseSessionRepository
    {
        public IDriver Driver { get; set; }

        public void IDatabaseSessionRepository()
        {
            Driver = GraphDatabase.Driver("bolt://localhost:8797", AuthTokens.Basic("neo4j", "neo4j"));

        }

        public ISession newSession()
        {
            return Driver.Session();
        }
    }

    public class DatabaseRepository : IDatabaseRepository
    {
        public ISession Session { get; set; }

        public void IDatabaseRepository()
        {
            //I want to access an instance of the DatabaseSessionRepository class
            //here 
        }

        //other methods here
    }
}
```

I want to have an instance of DatabaseSessionRepository and be able to access that within the DatabaseRepository class so I can get the ISession instance.

What I am thinking is that I could use the services.AddSingleton<>() on the DatabaseSessionRepository but then how do instantiate that only once and be able to access is within the DatabaseRepository class?

I will also use the services.AddScoped<>() lifetime for DatabaseRepository just so you know.

Comment: Why aren't you using constructor injection?  I'm not sure the DI system put forth by Microsoft in .NET Standard supports property based injection.

Comment: @casperOne He can just set AutoFAC as Di provider for attributes. But constructor injection is recommended. So just put a reference in the constructor to an interface and you will get the single instance no matter where you use it.

Comment: @FilipCordas so are you saying that I should just use the  services.AddSingleton<>() on IDatabaseSessionRepository.and then when I reference that in the constructor for IDatabaseRepository it will always just use the same instance automagically?

Comment: @ajanimember I am not saying it should be a singleton that is up to you to decide. But if you register a single instance it will only create one object per application.

Comment: Please keep in mind that `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInject` which is used in ASP.NET Core **is not specific to .NET Core**

Comment: @FilipCordas so how do I register a single instance? sorry if that seems obvious but I am fairly confused

Comment: @Tseng fair enough perhaps I should delete the asp.net-core tags then?

Comment: @ajanimember: It's an ASP.NET Core project so they are fine, since `Startup` class is ASP.NET Core specific though and the scope equals to a request in ASP.NET Core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't that be easier?

```
services.AddSingleton<IDriver>(p => GraphDatabase.Driver("bolt://localhost:8797", AuthTokens.Basic("neo4j", "neo4j"));
services.AddScoped<ISession>(p => p.GetService<IDriver>().Session());
```

This ensures that only one instance of an `IDriver` is created for the entire application lifetime and every time an `ISession` is requested it is resolved as a scoped service (a single `ISession` for an entire request) and disposed afterwards.

You then may inject `ISession` inside any controller:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly ISession _session;
    public MyController(ISession session)
    {
        _session = session;
    }
}
```

And of course inside any other class registered inside the DI container:

```
// inside ConfigureServices:    
services.AddScoped<IDatabaseRepository, DatabaseRepository>();

// your class:
public class DatabaseRepository : IDatabaseRepository
{
    public ISession Session { get; set; }

    public DatabaseRepository(ISession session)
    {
        Session = session;
    }

    //other methods here
}
```

Comment: I would not recommend doing ISession this way since `ISession` is `IDisposable` better to make  an `services.AddSingleton<Func<ISession>>(p =>()=> p.GetService<IDriver>().Session());` So you have control of when the session is disposed.

Comment: @FilipCordas The DI container [will dispose any `IDisposable` service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35872163/how-to-free-resources-and-dispose-injected-service-in-asp-net-5-core-by-the-end) after its scope has ended (in this case after an ASP.NET Core Request has finished). Registering a factory method is not necessary at all.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma True but this will still happen even if you don't use the session at all so it will just use time for no good reason It might be fine if you only use it at the action level with [FromServices] and not in the constructor.

Comment: @FilipCordas Why you would inject a dependency inside a class that does not use it? Your use case is very limited and will also cause multiple instances of `ISession` to be created inside the same HTTP request if the factory method is called multiple times. And this, in my opinion, is far more problematic then allowing a single `ISession` per request. Any modern DI framework (.NET Core included) solves this issue by using scoped lifetime.