# ASP.Net Core: Disposing of SSH client

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ssh, dependency-injection

I am using SSH.NET to connect to a database via ssh tunnel in an ASP.Net Core application.
I define a query session in the Startup.cs via dependency injection like this:

```
services.AddScoped<IQuerySession>(ds =>
{
    var store = ds.GetRequiredService<IDocumentStore>();
    using (var client = new SshClient("99.99.99.99", "admin", "test"))
    {
        client.Connect();

        return store.QuerySession();
    }
});
```

But how do I dispose of the ssh client when the scoped service is disposed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SshClient implements IDisposable so the .net framework will call Dispose() when the service is finished being used.

Good news, you don't have to do anything.

See here for more detail: [How to free resources and dispose injected service in ASP.NET 5/Core by the end of request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35872163/how-to-free-resources-and-dispose-injected-service-in-asp-net-5-core-by-the-end)